# How can I display a text file inside a switch statement in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, bufferedreader

I am trying to open a text file within a switch statement but I am getting the error 'Illegal start of expression'. I am new to Java so as simple as possible explanation would be appreciated!

Here is my code, ignore the other switch cases:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class journeyPlanner {
public static void main (String[] args){
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("  -- MAIN MENU -- \n 1: Display Journeys \n 2: Identify Suitable Journeys \n Q: Quit \n Pick:");
    String Choose = in.next();


    switch (Choose) {

        case "1" : BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader (<"Input.txt">));
                            break;

        case "2" : System.out.println("You answered: " + Choose + ". Please try again.");
                            break;

        case "Q" : System.out.println("You answered: " + Choose + ". That is correct!");
                            break;
            default:
            System.out.println("Please select a valid answer choice.");

    }
}
```

}

Comment: why are there `<` and `>` surrounding the filename?

Comment: You have multiple compilation erros, why not download an IDE like eclipse, it would help you out alot...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets break down the 3 things wrong here:

- `<` and `>` surrounding the filename
- duplicate variable declaration `in`
- missing `throws`

First off the compiler complains about the `<` and `>`. Fixing them will show problem number 2, fixing that will reveal problem number 3.

All three can be resolved by changing the `main` to throwing an exception (or alternatively / better catching it):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
```

**and** changing the `BufferedReader` line to:

```
case "1" : BufferedReader in2 = new BufferedReader(new FileReader ("Input.txt")); break;
```

Final recommendation: **indent your code properly**

Comment: and lets hope jre is 1.7 or above otherwise also the case "" will have problem...

Comment: @PetterFriberg okay, yes, completely forgot about that one since I am mostly working with 1.8

Answer (score 1):

Hum, you've got a duplicate variable `in` and you have a syntax error `new FileReader("Input.txt")`.

I suggest you to use a real ide that can help you on this kind of syntax errors...

Answer (score 0):

I think you got an syntax error there:

```
new FileReader (<"Input.txt">)
```

Remove the greater and lower than sign and it should work.
Another error is that you named two variables the same in ONE method:

```
Scanner in
```

and

```
BufferedReader in
```

I think it has nothing to do with the "switch/case" syntax.

To gain more "overview" over your switch case, you can set braces:

```
switch (bla) {
  case FOO: {
    // [...]
    break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well this worked for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, UnsupportedEncodingException {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("  -- MAIN MENU -- \n 1: Display Journeys \n 2: Identify Suitable Journeys \n Q: Quit \n Pick:");
    String Choose = in.next();

    switch (Choose) {

        case "1":
    {
        // first we'll try to open the file
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("Input.txt"));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
            // if the file does not exist, we'll create one
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("Input.txt", "UTF-8");
        }
    }
            break;
```

Of course I had to add some imports (BufferedReader, FileNotFoundException, FileReader, PrintWriter, UnsupportedEncodingException, Scanner).

The problem was that you have **already assigned variable in** (Scanner) and then you created BufferReader in.
Second problem was that you used angular brackets where you shouldn't.

You can skip the try catch block for checking the existence of the file. Hope it helps.